# DataTable DefaultView Rowfilter doesnt work

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a gridview that uses a DataTable as datasource. When I'm trying to hardcode the RowFilter string it works well, but when I use GetFilterExpression() it doesn't work. Why?

I've checked the string returned by GetFilterExpression and match it with an if check and I saw it exactly matches my hardcoded string.

```
var list = (List<ResaveBase>)listGridRows;
        var dt = ToDataTable(list);

        dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = GetFilterExpression(); //When hardcoding this, it works
        gvwResavePositions.DataSource = dt;
        gvwResavePositions.DataBind();


private string GetFilterExpression()
{
    string filterExpression = String.Empty;
    filterExpression = string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtPaperId.Text)
            ? string.Empty
            : string.Format("strPaperId IN ({0})", txtPaperId.Text);

    return filterExpression;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as per my knowledge expression must comes in quotation marks. it may possible your function results comes without quotes.
you can write logic in function and return value only and call function like -

```
String.Format("strPaperId IN ({0})", GetFilterExpression());
```

Answer (score 2):

This should fix it:

```
gvwResavePositions.DataSource = dt.DefaultView;
```